# How to Dart Interop this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dart, interop

```
g = new Graph();
g.edgeFactory.template.style.directed = true;
g.addNode("test");
layouter = new Graph.Layout.Ordered(g, topological_sort(g));
renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael("graphCanvas", g, width, height);
```

I've been trying to interop pieces of a Javascript library I use but the example interop didn't have anything in it that resembled Graph.Layout.Ordered. (this is the library I am using: http://www.graphdracula.net)

How would you interop something like that?

I came up with something like this. But it tosses an error that addNode cannot be found. Graph.prototype in the Javascript has the addNode function.

```
@anonymous
@JS('Graph.Layout')
class GraphLayoutOrdered {
  external void layout();
  external GraphLayoutOrdered(Graph g, List ts);
}
@anonymous
@JS('Graph.Renderer')
class RaphaelRenderer {
  external void draw();
  external RaphaelRenderer(String s, Graph g, int width, int height);
}
@anonymous
@JS("Graph")
class Graph {
  external Graph();
  external EdgeFactory get edgeFactory;
  external void addNode(String s, [Object content]);
  external void addEdge(var source, var target, var style);
}
@anonymous
@JS('Graph')
class EdgeFactory {
  external AbstractEdge get template;
}
@anonymous
@JS('EdgeFactory')
class AbstractEdge {
  external StyleObject get style;
}
@anonymous
@JS('AbstractEdge')
class StyleObject {
  external bool get directed;
  external set directed(bool b);
}
@anonymous
@JS()
external List topological_sort(Graph g);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many `@anonymous` annotations which not belong there.

So, for example, top-level function `topological_sort` probably should be defined as

```
@JS()
external List topological_sort(Graph g);
```

On the other hand, if on the javascript side StyleObject is plain map (not an object with constructor/prototype - whatnot) then it probably should be defined as

```
@anonymous
@JS()
class StyleObject {
  external bool get directed;
  external set directed(bool b);
}
```

**Update:**

Graph definition should do without `@anonymous` too. And probably without parameter in `@JS`. Like so:

```
@JS
class Graph {
  external Graph();
  external EdgeFactory get edgeFactory;
  external void addNode(String s, [Object content]);
  external void addEdge(var source, var target, var style);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already solved those two. They were definitely the easiest.

Right now I can't get addNode working in Graph. Even though I created the function.

Comment: If you marked Graph as `@anonymous` as in your example - I do not think methods in it would be accessible. I've updated my answer